# when running import nltk, Syntax Error is displayed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

File "/Users/zineb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 333
print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That looks like you've somehow managed to install a Python 3.x-only package into Python 2.x.

Comment: you should see here, it helps you ask your question in a better structure https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In case anyone comes here this solved my problem. You need to install older version of nltk.
pip install nltk==3.4.5

Answer (score 3):

1. You shouldn't be developing using python 2.7 anymore, 3.xx has been out for a long time and 2.x was EOL'd recently. Mac OS X has python3 installed as /usr/bin/python3.
2. To fix this error, you'll need to add from **future** import print_function at the top of /Users/zineb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py.

Comment: What about people already using it?

Comment: Given that it's now been [EOL](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), I'd suggest  an upgrade to 3.x was necessary yesterday.